# Ubuntu flqvour eqsiest on cpu

Tags: kubuntu, hardware, cpu

I have this macbook air from mid 2011 and I want  to use an ubuntu based distro on it. At the moment I'm using kubuntu but my one problem is that my cpu sometimes has alof of difficulties keeping up with what I'm throwing at it. Is there a flavour that makes a noticeable difference in cpu usage or is it all so small that when it hits 100% on kubuntu nothing will make it better?

What I'm also wondering is if different ubuntu flavours or distros in general can react different when the same program runs. So for example when I run a program on ubuntu and on kubuntu that there could be a noticable difference in hardware resources or is this not really a thing and can I just look at cpu usage from the flavour/distro itself?

Comment: Sounds like a dual-core i5 or i7 with up to 4GB RAM. That's a little *lean* by modern standards. It's less important what desktop you use, but more useful to know what applications / tasks you're hoping to throw at it. Chances are any modern browser will eat the RAM more than the desktop will.

Comment: @popey well ram whise I’m fine atm. About 3 gigs with everything I want to do now. And that’s very light programming work. Sometimes this very light macbook is so very convenient whilst my bigger laptop is just a little to heavy. That’s why I’m seeing what I can do with this. One thing I do see is that the macbook really starts dying when I open up a program or compile and run some kind of programming work, after it’s mostly fine